# JQuery FileUpload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I would like to know how to call a function right after all files are loaded. Not when they are uploaded, I mean right after their html is loaded.

I want to trigger my function exactly after all the files are selected by the user. After they appear on screen. I want to make changes on their HTML, so I need to trigger my function not only after the user selects the files, but after the files' HTML are created.

Here's the API I'm using: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Please provide the result of your research, what you've tried or done so far

Answer (score 0):

I think this might solve your problem. You should look into this: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API#Callbacks

> The second way of using them is by binding event listeners to the
>   widget element:
>
> $('#fileupload')
>
> ```
> .bind('fileuploaddrop', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
>
> .bind('fileuploadchange', function (e, data) {/* ... */}); Each event name has "fileupload" as prefix.
> ```
>
> Note: Adding additional event listeners via bind method is the
>   preferred option to preserve callback settings by the jQuery File
>   Upload UI version.

So you can just do your custom event e.g. called `fileuploadcomplete` or whatever suits you best.

Comment: I already saw theese callbacks... the one that is closest to what I need is the "add", but it runs BEFORE each line is added. I want one to run AFTER each line is added.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I searched a little deeper